# ftpclient via 3g

Tags: java, android, ftp, apache-commons

I am using Apache Commons ftp client to upload a file to a server.   If I have a wi-fi connection to my home router all goes well.  If I dont have that wi-fi connection the 3G icon appears in the notification bar but the ftp.connect gives an error 'connection reset by peer'.   I've googled around for this but not found anything that helps.  Is ftpclient not able to work with 3G?

Answer (score 3):

A regular FTP file transfer (in active mode) uses two connections - one established by the client and one established from the server for transferring the data. As 3G connections are usually firewalled by a NAT system the server can not reach the client. Therefore only connections in passive mode are possible.

Have you tried to use the passive mode. It should be configurable by calling `enterLocalPassiveMode()` on the [FtpClient](http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) instance.

Comment: May be your mobile network operator prohibits tethering and thinks that cell phones do not use FTP... Have you checked what happens if you use a tethered PC and a regular FTP client? If it still goes wrong you know that it is not your fault or you may capture the problem using Wireshark.